# How to create a folder under %allusersprofile% during Setup with VS 2003 Setup Project?

Tags: installation, setup-project, visual-studio-2003, programdata

I need to create a folder under "%allusersprofile%/Program Data" during the install process.

The Setup file is created with VS 2003 setup project, and in it you can use several Known Folders... but as I see none maps to %allusersprofile% or "%allusersprofile%/Program Data".

I thought that creating a "Custom Folder" (within VS Setup Project) and setting the TargetLocation as %allusersprofile% it would work, but during install it says that I don't have permission to that folder (and I do have).

**Do you know how to target that folder in VS Setup Project?**

Also...
I'm working in Windows XP, so %allusersprofile% maps to "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users", but there I suppose I should create my folder inside the "Program Data" folder.

In Vista, %allusersprofile% maps to "C:\ProgramData" and it look correct if I create my folder directly there.

**Any idea how to target both OSs?**

**Additional info:**
I'm trying this to avoid the new security features in Vista, where the app can't write files under the Program Files folder when running as a common user at least. So I need to place the writable files on "common" folder that is not in a "per user" basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved...
In VS Setup Project you can create a folder saying that the DefaultLocation is: `[CommonAppDataFolder]\[ProductName]`

That works fine in MS Vista and in XP